# Can a eunuch bring a burnt offering?

Tags: korban, isaiah-yeshaya-the-book

I'm looking at Yeshayahu 56:4,7

> For so says the Lord to the eunuchs who will keep My Sabbaths and will choose what I desire and hold fast to My covenant,...I will bring them to My holy mount, and I will cause them to rejoice in My house of prayer, their burnt offerings and their sacrifices shall be acceptable upon My altar, for My house shall be called a house of prayer for all peoples.

How should I understand this verse? Will the eunuchs serve as cohanim and bring burnt offerings? This would seem to contradict the Torah.

Or should I understand that eunuchs will bring burnt offerings for qualified cohanim to offer up? This would seem to make more sense.

I've read the Rashi on this but he doesn't seem to comment on the issues I am raising.

Answer (score 3):

Eunuchs are like everyone else who is not a kohein. They bring their sacrifices to the Temple, and the kohanim offer them on their behalf, but it is still considered their korban. A kohein who is a eunuch is not able to serve in the Temple, and must use another kohein. (Mishna Bechoros 6:6 and 7:1)

Comment: But a kohein who is a eunuch is still a kohen and can eat the kohen reserved parts of korbanos.  Just another kohen has to bring them.